# What else we miss?

Tags: secondary-education, reference-request, teachers

**Context:**

Some time ago there was a post on a brief study conducted by Alexis Wiggins (she was shadowing two students for two days), you can find it [here](https://grantwiggins.wordpress.com/2014/10/10/a-veteran-teacher-turned-coach-shadows-2-students-for-2-days-a-sobering-lesson-learned/), which [got quite an attention](https://grantwiggins.wordpress.com/2014/10/19/a-ps-to-the-guest-post-on-shadowing-hs-students-and-the-author-revealed/). One interesting thing is that, as the author of the blog have put it, it is "not news". To be more precise, let me quote a paragraph:

> **Not news.** Yet, as a number of commenters pointed out – and I agree – the passive and sitting life of a HS student is not news. Our surveys document this, and I have written about my own observations of the boredom I see. Ted Sizer’s Coalition of Essential Schools (for which I worked as the 1st director of research 30 years ago) began life due to *Horace’s Compromise* and *The Shopping Mall HS* which both documented the problem (along with massive data from John Goodlad’s *A Place Called School*). All of which was preceded by Postman & Weingartner, Kozol, Silbermann and Friedenberg in the 60s.
>
> [Grant Wiggins, [A PS to the guest post on shadowing HS students (and the author revealed)](https://grantwiggins.wordpress.com/2014/10/19/a-ps-to-the-guest-post-on-shadowing-hs-students-and-the-author-revealed)]

But despite the fact that it is not news, Alexis, "a veteran HS teacher who just became a Coach" states

> I have made a terrible mistake. I waited fourteen years to do something that I should have done my first year of teaching: shadow a student for a day.

and later in the article follows with a number of changes she would immediately implement.

**My question:** What else we miss?

I would suspect that a veteran teacher would know something about the students' daily routine. From the story she told, it is clear it was not enough (at least for her). As someone with much less experience I'm concerned about other things that we (as teachers and educators) are unaware of that hurt our students the most. What I'm looking for, is a collection of posts, statements, research results, that would help getting the fundamentals right (I regard the students' inability to follow the lesson quite fundamental). The scenario I'm counting for is that we crowd-source such a list here, each of us contributing some important bits (the perspectives vary, collaboration might result in a more balanced collection).

**A follow up:** Is missing such things very bad, and if it is, how we can prevent missing such things? (Perhaps that should be another question, I will separate it if there is enough interest in it.)

**P.S.** I'm aware that this question is more about teaching in general than teaching mathematics, but I don't know any other SE site that fits better (and there surely are some math-related issues too, I just don't know how they compare).